# Can you point custom domain to Application Load Balancer URL instead of EB URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have an EB application with an ALB. I want my app to be accessible under a custom domain. Is it okay to point my custom domain directly to the ALB instead of the EB app URL?

I am wondering if there is any reason not to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason I could think of that you will loose some of EB automated functionality with that, and will have to **manually correct** your custom DNS record. Examples are:

- Changing config of your EB environment - from load balanced to single instance, or change load balancer. In that case EB url is preserved, but obviously your custom DNS record will be invalid since it will be pointing to already non-existing ALB.
- Blue green deployments - their are done in EB by swap of EB CNAMEs, so again your custom DNS will need manual setup to point to new load balancer.